# Ant deisgn set field value for an array field

Tags: antd

I am new to ant design 4.0.1. I want to set field value for a an array field using the index. This is what I have currently done. I want to know the correct syntax. Assistance will be greatly appreciated.

```
 form.setFieldsValue({
      [("userPaymentInstruction", `${index}`, "payment_provider_id")]: "",
    });
```

Comment: which version of ant design?

Comment: ant design 4.0.1